# To get all operations on what tables from which stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

Suppose I have `table_A` & `table_B` and `sp_A` (with dynamic query in the stored procedure) as shown below:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_A]
AS  
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM table_A
    
    DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'UPDATE table_B SET col_2 = 2 WHERE col_1 = 1'
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
END
GO
```

I would like to have a list of result, the stored procedure doing what operation on which table.

Sample of result as below:

```
SP_Name   Table_Name   Operation
--------------------------------
sp_A       table_A      SELECT
sp_A       table_b      UPDATE
```

I understand that we can use `sql_expression_dependencies` to find all dependencies on stored procedures & tables:

```
SELECT 
    sp.[name] AS 'SP_Name', o.[name] AS 'Table_Name', sp.[type_desc]
FROM
    sys.objects AS o
INNER JOIN 
    sys.sql_expression_dependencies AS sed on o.[object_id] = sed.referenced_id
INNER JOIN 
    sys.objects AS sp ON sed.referencing_id = sp.[object_id] 
                      AND sp.[type] IN ('P', 'FN')
WHERE 
    o.[name] IN ('table_A', 'table_B')
ORDER BY 
    sp.[name]
```

But this only applies for non-dynamic query stored procedures, in my case, I do have dynamic query in my stored procedure.

Also by using `sql_expression_dependencies`, we can only know what table but can't really get what operation (SELECT/INSERT/UPDATE) on the table

Comment: You might need to write code that analyze the dynamic sql from the stored procedure's code. Here's an article that lists 4 ways to get the procedure's code: https://database.guide/4-ways-to-get-a-stored-procedures-definition-using-transact-sql/

Comment: Why do you want this? Are you trying to find what permissions are required to execute an arbitrary SQL script? A dynamic query is nothing more than a string until it gets executed. The server knows nothing about that string until then. In any case operations aren't dependencies.

Comment: There is no easy way of doing this, unless you're ready to parse arbitrary dynamic code. You sure you need this?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks for your comment. Yes, I need to know which SP is using what operation so that I can plan and assign table permission to related tables.

Comment: @siggemannen yes I understand the difficulty and still looking and trying how to achieve this. And sure, I need this.

Comment: If i were to solve it, i'd use antlr to parse the code into some sort of AST. It allows you to have a list of statements and expressions down. But that's the easy part! Then, you need to find all exec / execute statements, and somehow trace back either the dynamic string or the variable containing some strings. If someone is funny enough to build a statement like: set sql = 'update from ' + @tableName then you also need to somehow trace that back. finally, when you found the strings, you need to parse them again, to figure out the actual SQL in the string, and then you'd be done

Comment: But this is so hard that i doubt anyone but the best guys could pull it off. Perhaps you could make a simpler version that tracks all strings in procedure that matches names of you tables and go from there

Comment: You could narrow it down by only checking procedures with execute. But another issue is tracking calls over multiple procedures. Like: you have one generic update procedure which accepts table name as parameter. then you'd be screwed. Why do you even need this, and how many procedures are we talking about

Comment: " I can plan and assign table permission to related tables" - a proc permission overrides whatever rights table needs anyway, so, why do you need the rights assigned

Comment: @siggemannen Thanks for your advice and this helped me a lots!
"a proc permission overrides whatever rights table needs" this is true if only the SP is using normal query. A dynamic query will break the dependencies and hence will need the particular table permission. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yeah. Then you're smoked :D